# Applying style to separate element based on clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little JS/Jquery issue with my portfolio website and I still consider myself a mediocre programmer.

I have five buttons on my portfolio website, each representing one of my projects. I also have a div with five matching text contents (as a description for each of the projects) and an image/link as a visual description of the project with link on the image so the user can go to the project URL.

```
<div class="work-content">
    <h2 class="con-active" id="contentOne">Content One</h2>
    <h2 class="con-hidden" id="contentTwo">Content Two</h2>
    <h2 class="con-hidden" id="contentThree">Content Three</h2>
    <h2 class="con-hidden" id="contentFour">Content Four</h2>
    <h2 class="con-hidden" id="contentFive">Content Five</h2>
</div>
<div class="moving-zone" style="z-index: 0;">
    <a href="about.html" class="popup" id="popupOne">
        <div class="popup-content">Background One</div>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="popup is-hidden" id="popupTwo">
        <div class="popup-content">Background Two</div>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="popup is-hidden" id="popupThree">
        <div class="popup-content">Background Three</div>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="popup is-hidden" id="popupFour">
        <div class="popup-content">Background Four</div>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="popup is-hidden" id="popupFive">
        <div class="popup-content">Background Five</div>
    </a>
</div>
<ul class="work-ul">
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workOne">WORK</button></li>
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workTwo">WORK</button></li>
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workThree">WORK</button></li>
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workFour">WORK</button></li>
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workFive">WORK</button></li>
</ul>
```

The idea is: when a user enters the page, it will be showing the first project (meaning the first description and first image with the link will be active and showing - probably having class "is-active"). When the user clicks any of the buttons, it will hide the description and image that's being shown already and show the one matching the project button (So if I click the third button, it will hide the first description and first image and show the third description and third image)

I am not really good with arrays and Each functions, plus I am baffled by how to remove the "is-active" class form all non-desired elements and then add that class to the elements I want to show.

NOTE: If you would use a different HTML markup, it's more than welcome. This is just first iteration and I have been stuck on this for past day.

Comment: The basic idea is "user clicks X" -> hide all -> show content X. Not to be rude, but this is really trivial stuff. "hide all" is just `$(".work-content h2").hide()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I like to use the `data-*` attributes for this situation.

Give the button a `data-id` attribute.
Give the corresponding elements (header and anchor) a `data-content` attribute with the same value as above.

Then on the click of the button, first hide all the elements with a `data-content` attribute, the show the ones which `data-content` attribute corresponds with the `data-id` attribute.

So might be able to lose some `id` attributes, but that you should judge yourself.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('[data-content]').hide();
    $('[data-content="'+id+'"]').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.con-hidden,
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work-content">
    <h2 class="con-active" id="contentOne" data-content="1">Content One</h2>
    <h2 class="con-hidden" id="contentTwo" data-content="2">Content Two</h2>
    <h2 class="con-hidden" id="contentThree" data-content="3">Content Three</h2>
    <h2 class="con-hidden" id="contentFour" data-content="4">Content Four</h2>
    <h2 class="con-hidden" id="contentFive" data-content="5">Content Five</h2>
</div>
<div class="moving-zone" style="z-index: 0;">
    <a href="about.html" class="popup" id="popupOne" data-content="1">
        <div class="popup-content">Background One</div>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="popup is-hidden" id="popupTwo" data-content="2">
        <div class="popup-content">Background Two</div>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="popup is-hidden" id="popupThree" data-content="3">
        <div class="popup-content">Background Three</div>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="popup is-hidden" id="popupFour" data-content="4">
        <div class="popup-content">Background Four</div>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="popup is-hidden" id="popupFive" data-content="5">
        <div class="popup-content">Background Five</div>
    </a>
</div>
<ul class="work-ul">
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workOne" data-id="1">WORK</button></li>
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workTwo" data-id="2">WORK</button></li>
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workThree" data-id="3">WORK</button></li>
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workFour" data-id="4">WORK</button></li>
    <li class="work-link"><button class="button" id="workFive" data-id="5">WORK</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked absolute wonders. Will keep this in mind in the future. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer suits you, please mark it as solution (hitting the v-mark on the left)

Comment: Actually, now after some testing, the function doesn't seem to fire when I leave the page and then come back (I am using barba.js so when I move around the website, it doesn't reload entire HTML, just the container) It only works when I reload the page. It doesn't show me any errors and when I console log it, It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok now, this looks like a sperate issue from the original problem (probably connected with the barba thing), so I am gonna mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using your current setup, you could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.work-ul button').each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(function(o) {
            $('.work-content h2, div.moving-zone a').hide();
            $('.work-content h2:eq('+i+'), div.moving-zone a:eq('+i+')').show();
        });
    });
});
```

You'll want some initial styles/class to hide all but perhaps your first portfolio item.

Comment: Why the `each()` function?

Comment: @LinkinTED passing in the index

Comment: No need for that. Use `$('.work-ul button').function() { var i = $(this).index(); });`

Comment: doesn't `.index()` iterate? i.e. `each()`? Only instead of once on instantiation, it does it everytime when a button is clicked? Unless jQuery is caching the index of the object somewhere, under the hood, an iteration would be run for every call to `.index()`